# How to get names of the struct members from QMetaType?

Tags: c++, qt, enums, metadata

I have:

```
struct myStruct {
    int m_valueA;
    float m_valueA;
    bool m_valueA;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(myStruct)

....

struct myStructXY {
    ....
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(myStructXY)
```

I can get enum names from `QMetaEnum`:

```
Q_ENUM(myEnum)
QMetaEnum enumTypes QMetaEnum::fromType<myEnum>();

QMap<qint32, QString> labelsMap;
for(int i = 0; i < enumTypes.keyCount(); i++)
{
    QString enumName = QString(enumTypes.key(i));
    labelsMap.insert(enumTypes.value(i), enumName);
}
```

I would like to dynamicaly collect the `myStruct` members names and types from metatype similar as in previuos case of Enums.
Like:

```
QMetaObject structType;
QStringList list = getStructMemberNames(structType);
```

Does Qt have an option to do this?
I have searched the [QMetaType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) but I need more power to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there are any mean to do this in Qt.

The closest thing would be QMetaObject which exposes signals, slots and properties; properties could be seen like exposing member variables, but that is not exactly what you asked.

Also note that QMetaEnum works only if you used Q_ENUM in a QObject class processed by the moc. So for making something similar with a struct it would work only with struct inside QObjects anddeclared with a Q_STRUCT, but as of now this does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get names of struct members from QMetaType?

Not using Qt to begin with, since `moc` does not support generating such metadata. That's all. If you wish, you could patch `moc` to do it for you, but out of the box it doesn't work. You would probably have more success by getting the [AST from clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html), generating some metadata records from it, and adding it to your code.